# Is there a way (in java) to generate human editable Microsoft Word documents from human readable template?

Tags: java, templates, report, reporting

I am searching for a way for my Java application to generate Word document using some kind of Template (the data for the document will be provided by the application)
Here are the requirements : 
 - The template should be editable for a non-developper human being. Creating a Jasper template using the adequate tool or editing a Word document with some kind of templating language is compliant. Asking for editing the xml file of the document is not
 - The results should be easily editable for a human being, using Microsoft Word. For example, the document generated by Jasper or Birt is not compliant, as the table layout prevent any easy edition.

For the moment, I looked at the following solutions, finding no one which match the two requirements :

- Jasper. The document generated are not easily edited
- Birt. Same Problem
- Generating the xml using a template motor (velocity, Freemarker). I cannot ask for the final client to edit this kind of XML file...

Answer (score 2):

You can check out Templater. It has pretty good [demo page](http://templater.info/demo).

Disclamer: I'm the author.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Templater seems to be exactly what I need, without being off-budget. I will come back after testing it.

Answer (score 1):

## LibreOffice

[LibreOffice](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice) is an open-source implementation of an app suite similar to Microsoft Office. Besides supporting the standardized [OpenDocument](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) format, it also reads and writes Microsoft Office formats.

LibreOffice offers a [Java API](http://api.libreoffice.org). So you may be able to programmatically create documents from a template.

In the past we’ve done something similar, modifying a document with search-and-replace and document-variables.

## Apache Poi

[Apache Poi](https://poi.apache.org) is an open-source library for reading and writing Microsoft Office compatible documents.

I don't know its details but you might take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I have no problem working with Word Document in Java (I already used Apache Poi), but it is the template motor part which is important for me.

Answer (score 1):

[JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) (open source) and [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) (commercial) are designed to use normal/human-managed documents as templates (Word, OpenOffice, etc), merge in your data and return editable documents, PDFs etc.  Please note I work for Docmosis.

Both JODReports and Docmosis provide a Java API.

If you are interested in automating Open Office or Libre Office directly (as mentioned in Basil's answer), [this blog about converting Doc to Pdf](http://www.docmosis.com/company/blog/item/java-convert-word-to-pdf-part-1.html)  will give you a quick-start to:

1. load a doc file as a template
2. search and replace
3. export to file (pdf in the example)

To change the output format to Doc instead of PDF:

```
 propertyValues[1].Value = "writer_pdf_Export";
```

to

```
 propertyValues[1].Value = "MS Word 97";
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will take a look, but at first sight, Docmosis seems to be off budget, and JODReport has not been updated in a while. I hope it is usable...

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for this kind of solution as well, and I found [XDocReport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport), including an [example of a table](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingJavaMainListFieldInTable). I will give it a try.